# 不定形な形はUnityでどうやって実現すればよいでしょうか？

Tags: unity3d, unity2d, directx

画像の土の部分のような不定形な形をコードで実現するにはどうやればよいでしょうか？
画像は [Water Rush](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/water-rush/id1464015901) というゲームの画面です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]